# CommonLoggingErrorHandler behaviour

Tags: spring-kafka

I have the following settings:

```
      @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> batchContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> containerFactory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    containerFactory.setConsumerFactory(batchConsumerFactory());
    containerFactory.setBatchListener(true);

    ContainerProperties containerProperties = containerFactory.getContainerProperties();
    containerProperties.setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.BATCH);

    CommonLoggingErrorHandler commonLoggingErrorHandler = new CommonLoggingErrorHandler();
    commonLoggingErrorHandler.setAckAfterHandle(false);
    containerFactory.setCommonErrorHandler(commonLoggingErrorHandler);

    return containerFactory;
  }
```

For the sake of testing this, I created this listener:

```
  @KafkaListener(id = "customer-topic", containerFactory = "batchContainerFactory",
      topics = {"#{kafkaApplicationProperties.customers}"},
      groupId = "#{kafkaApplicationProperties.groupId}",
      clientIdPrefix = "#{kafkaApplicationProperties.clientIdPrefix}",
      concurrency = "#{kafkaApplicationProperties.concurrency}")
  public void masterDataListener(@Payload List<ConsumerRecord<String, ContractCustomerEvent>> customers) {

    log.info("Min offset {}, size {}",
        customers.stream().map(this::partitionAndOffset).sorted().findFirst().orElseThrow(),
        customers.size());

    if (customers.stream().anyMatch(customer -> customerData.containsKey(customer.value().getId()))) {
      log.info("Has seen"); //never called as none of the records is replayed
    }
    customers.forEach(customer -> customerData.put(customer.value().getId(), customer.value()));
    if (counter.get().getAndIncrement() < 5) {
      log.info("Boom");
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Boom");
    }
    customers.forEach(customer -> afterEx.put(customer.value().getId(), customer.value())); //afterEx and customerData is not equal, afterEx contains less records, these are lost
  }

...
//somewhere to log the offsets
private Object getOffsets(AdminClient adminClient) { 
  return adminClient.listConsumerGroupOffsets(kafkaApplicationProperties.getGroupId()).all()
       .whenComplete((result, throwable) -> log.info("######## {}", result, throwable));
}
```

Because `setAckAfterHandle` is set to `false`, I would expect that the first records (which arrived during the call when the exception was still thrown) would be replayed, but actually the listener continues with a batch not including the previous records and eventually the offset is committed and so messages are lost.

Is that the expected behaviour of this error handler? If yes, what is the purpose of the `ackAfterHandle` property?

I can eventually see this:

```
2023-10-12T12:32:51.376+02:00 INFO 5756 --- [| adminclient-2] a.r.l.k.c.KafkaTopicListenerITTest : ######## {my-group={my-customers-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=50000, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, my-customers-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=50000, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a basic misunderstanding of how Kafka works; it maintains two pointers, the last committed offset and the current position. They are completely unrelated except that the current position is set to the last committed offset when the consumer first starts.

Not committing an offset does not change the current position; the next poll will not return the same record.

`ackAfterHandle` simply means that if the error handler does not throw an exception, the offset will be committed; setting it to false simply means the offset won't be committed, but that still does not change the current position.

The `DefaultErrorHandler` performs a seek on the failed record (and any following records from the last poll), to change the current position, so that the record is redelivered (until retries are exhausted).

Comment: so if the error handler does not throw, eventually the batch ack mode will trigger the offset commit. in case ackAfterHandle is true, this might be triggered directly by the error handler (maybe sooner). do I get this totally wrong?

Comment: Don't put code in comments - it is impossible to read; delete these, edit the question then comment that you have done so. No; it is not "triggered by the error handler". In batch mode, if all records are successful (or handled by an error handler), offsets for the entire batch are committed after the last record in the batch is processed. `ackAfterHandle` is really only meaningful for `AckMode.RECORD`.

Comment: Your last answer confirms my assumptions about the `ackAfterHandle` property in batch mode.